# Function to detect another worksheet change event in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a function in lets say 'Sheet1', to detect a cell change on 'Sheet2' and update some values in Sheet1. 
I cannt use worksheet change event on Sheet2, cause Sheet1 gets duplicated and I need to carry this code while duplication. 
Is there a way I can write Worksheet_Change event in Sheet1 for Sheet2?

Comment: You can do it with event sinks but it's going to be hard to maintain. It would be much easier to have some sort of identifier on Sheet1 (and its copies) that Sheet2 can use to populate the relevant cells on any sheet with that identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're after - maybe this is a step in the right direction:

Add a class module called **clsSheet2Events**.  Add this code to the module:

```
Private WithEvents SheetEvent As Worksheet
Private ThisSheet As Worksheet

Public Property Set Attach_SheetEvent(Value As Worksheet)
    Set SheetEvent = Value
End Property
Public Property Set Attach_ThisSheet(Value As Worksheet)
    Set ThisSheet = Value
End Property

Private Sub SheetEvent_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    MsgBox Target.Address & " on " & Target.Parent.Name & " has changed." & vbCr & _
        "Updating value on " & ThisSheet.Name

    ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "I've changed"

End Sub
```

In a normal module, or in the worksheet module enter this code:

```
Public Sub DetectSheetEvent()

    Dim Sheet2Class As clsSheet2Events
    Set Sheet2Class = New clsSheet2Events

    Set Sheet2Class.Attach_SheetEvent = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set Sheet2Class.Attach_ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = "A"

End Sub
```

When you run the DetectSheetEvent code the class module will start monitoring the worksheet events on Sheet2 and update a value in Sheet1 if a change event occurs - which fires when A is entered to Sheet2 cell A1.

Comment: Actually I need to include the Sheet2 change event in Sheet1's module.. the only reason is that Sheet1 gets duplicated for different revisions and I need this Sheet2 change event getting copied every time Sheet1 is getting duplicated.